# Laravel Passport - /oauth/token generates invalid token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

So I created a client using `php artisan passport:client`, and when I do a POST request to oauth/token I thankfully get back a token.

However, when I try to use that token by putting it in my headers and going to an `auth:api` protected route I get 401 unauthorized.

Using a different route to login, however, seems to work. When I use this route in my api controller:

```
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

which has the following code:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'] ])) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return [
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $user->createToken('test')->accessToken
        ];
    }

    return [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'unable to authenticate'
    ];
}
```

I get back a token that works on protected routes.

I'm using Postman to test, I have headers `Authorization: Bearer <token>` and `Accept: application/json`. Not sure why it works one way but not another.

edit: Here is the protected route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) 
{
    return $request->user();
});
```

which uses:

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: What does the rest of you `api` middleware contain?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Have you checked that the returned token exists in the database? Also, you passed in an empty scopes, that might be affecting things as well.

Comment: it does, but i noticed that the user_id column is null for that token. however the client im using to authenticate with has a user_id associated with it

Comment: You just answered your own question, you need to figure out why `user_id` isn't getting set.

Comment: that wasn't the issue unfortunately. i manually set user_id to something in sequel pro and i'm still getting unauthenticated.

Comment: What web server are you using, apache, nginx, or artisan serve?

Comment: apache right now

Comment: Apache is notorious for stripping the `Authorization` header. You'll want to verify you have that header in the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case remove the Lsapi component from WHM server and function.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please add context, and an explanation as to why this might work as a solution. If it makes sense to do so, also explain how to do this. As is, your response, is likely more useful as a Comment to the OP, and might not be considered a full and proper Answer as per SO guidelines. A useful answer would be a self contained solution that leaves future visitors with additional knowledge they can apply to their own situations. Quality informative answers are more likely to be upvoted, meanwhile Low quality answers are likely to be download, or removed altogether.