# Laravel 5.7 passport return Unauthenticated always on AWS server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2, laravel-passport

I am facing laravel authentication issue. I follow the Laravel 5.7 official docs to handle authentication. It works on localhost but when deployed on AWS server, it gives unauthenticate message. 
Each login time new token generate but Laravel doesn't authenticate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether are using passport or what you are using for token... 
But i think the keys generated on your localhost for signing the tokens are different from the one on AWS... If you can manually migrate the keys to server (which is a bad idea)..
The regenerate a new one on the AWS... I don't if am clear enough...

To add to it... The key are normally located under the storage dir... (both public and private...) But better to generate a new one instead...

Comment: we are using passpoert api  laravel for OAuth

Answer (score 0):

```
Apache is notorious for stripping the Authorization header. You'll want to verify you 
have that header in the incoming request.
Please add this (/etc/apache2/sites-available)

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/429869/is-this-a-correct-way-to-enable-htaccess-in-apache-2-4-7

[Laravel Passport - /oauth/token generates invalid token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006058/laravel-passport-oauth-token-generates-invalid-token)